# Angular Material drag from list into container

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I am trying to do something that looks possible with angular material, but I am not sure.
I have a table of items that I want to be able to drag from one list to another container, but I don't want the container to sort the list, rather keep the position I drop it to.

I tried doing this initially like this:

```
<div class="container" cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="list-1" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <ul>
      <li cdkDrag *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item.name}}

        <div class="example-drag" *cdkDragPreview>
          {{item.name}}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-2" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="done" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-drop" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".list-2" *ngFor="let item of done">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But that just drops it into a second list and orders it. That is not the behaviour I want.
Here is a stackblitz showing what I want the **second** container to act like:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nc3wps

Here is an example of my failed attempt:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4dcyd1

And this is trying to combine the two:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m2ewfh

Hopefully this is enough information for someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this property to disable sorting in target container

```
cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
```